# Как анимировать элементы на QQuickPaintedItem?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Хочу чтобы вся анимация и все отображение виджета было в с++ коде
Если упрощенно. то виджет представляет собой 10 окружностей на которых расположены "красные круглешки" .
При изменении значений, они должны передвинуться, естественно, по своей окружности.
в идеале я хочу, чтобы паинт() циферблата отрабатывал только при измении размера, а сами эти красные точки обрабатывались в паинте независимо, чтобы на них натянуть QPropertyAnimation

Comment: или это все чепуха и надо анимацию лепить на qml слое?

Comment: Анимации на свойствах вроде работают, нет? То есть вы говорите, что у вас есть свойство X, потом говорите что хотите анимацию - изменять X от 0 до 100 (условно, я не шарю), а когда рисуете свой item, читаете значение свойства, и в зависимости от его значения так или иначе рисуетесь. Так образом анимация - это про изменение свойства